# Why does the function return these values?

Tags: javascript, function

This function counts events from [a file](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/jacques_journal.js) and stores them in an array.

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
    if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1; //9
    if (entry.squirrel) index += 2; //4
    table[index] += 1;
  }
  return table;
}
console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
```

Why does this function return `//76, 9, 4, 1`? The numbers should be `//74, 10, 5, 1`.

I considered the function starts counting from zero, but I don't think so.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add the value of `entry.events` and `entry.squirrel`.

Comment: 9 is returned because line 51 `{"events":["pizza","peanuts","candy","work"],"squirrel":true}`, sum to the wrong index... For the rest of positions, `if` condition may change index...

Comment: well... now it's clear and that was ridiculous question from my side. Thank you a lot!

Comment: What exactly is `table` supposed to count?

Comment: Why do you think the numbers should be `74, 10, 5, 1`??? [The book expects `[76, 9, 4, 1]`!](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#c_5+RytkZMOT)

Answer (score -1):

The best approach is this implementation...

events = 90,

pizza = 10,

squirrel:true = 5,

pizza and squirrel:true = 1, so we need to rest `-2` in the implementation

90 - 10 - 5 - 1 = 74

```js
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    var entry = journal[i];
    if(hasEvent(event, entry) && entry.squirrel) table[3] += 1; //1
    if(entry.squirrel) table[2] += 1; //5
    if(hasEvent(event, entry)) table[1] += 1; //10
    if(!(hasEvent(event, entry) || entry.squirrel)) table[0] += 1; //76
    // xor
    if(hasEvent(event, entry) && entry.squirrel) table[0] -= 2; //74
  }
  return table;
}
console.log("Expected: 74,10,5,1")
console.log("Calculated: " + tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
```

```html
<script src="http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/jacques_journal.js"></script>
```

Comment: You probably want `else if`… or explicitly do `if (a && b)…; if (a && !b)…; if (!a && b)…; if (!a && !b)…;`